# Unable to write to xls, php or doc files using Python

Tags: python, sockets, file-io

I am having problems writing the data from the client side to server side into .xls, .php or .doc files. Here's my server's side code

```
amtOfFilesHeader = ""
while True:
    d = connectionSocket.recv(1)
    if d == '\n':
        break
    amtOfFilesHeader += d
amtOfFiles = int(amtOfFilesHeader.split()[-1])
while amtOfFiles > 0:
    header = ""
    while True:
        d = connectionSocket.recv(1)
        if d == '\n':
            break
        header += d

    filesize = int(header.split()[-1])
    # or search for the last space in header
    # and get a substring of header as filename
    filename = "".join(header.split()[1:-1])
    data = ""
    while filesize > 0:
        chunk = connectionSocket.recv(1) # or any amount of data
        filesize -= len(chunk)
        data += chunk
    file = open((server_side_folder+'/'+filename),'wb')
    file.write(data)
    file.close()
    amtOfFiles-=1
```

I keep getting errors such as:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'server_side/test.xls'
```

although I have already open the file for writing. Did I do something wrong in the code?

Comment: Is the file in the same dir as the script?

Comment: Use absolute paths; your current directory is not what you think it is. Make sure that the `server_side` folder *exists* too.

Comment: Before your `open` call, print or log the following information: `os.path.abspath(server_side_folder+'/'+filename)`.

Comment: Other type of files (.txt, .jpg) files do not have such problem so I think it is not a directory issue...

Comment: If `.txt` is ok and `.xls` is not, you may want to check for anti-malware programs.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find where is the bug. It turns out that the timeout for my server and client threads is too short. After I increase the timeout, I can read in .xls, .php and .php files.